# angular2 and nativescript does not work - assertion failed: 15G1004 14A345: libxpc.dylib

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am been having a terrible time getting nativescript to work with angular 2 with the official release.  I am zero issues with good ole faction web angular but native script is a different story. NativeScript why will my hello world work?  I see nothing.

Thanks

Home:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    template: "hello",
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router){
    }
}
```

app

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "main",
    template: "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>",
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Routes:

```
import { HomeComponent } from "./pages/home/home.component";

export const routes = [
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent }
];

export const navigatableComponents = [

    HomeComponent
];
```

Modules:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./pages/home/home.component";
import { routes, navigatableComponents } from "./app.routes";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent,
   ...navigatableComponents ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}



Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/Documents/frontend/bootops-mobile-v1/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Transferring project files...
Successfully transferred all files.
Applying changes...
Sep 17 23:05:18 Davids-iMac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D28D29C3-07B6-4B60-B4B0-711475C505DE.launchd_sim[19187] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.bootopsmobilev1[0x7351][20309]): Service exited due to Terminated: 15
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.bootopsmobilev1 on device D28D29C3-07B6-4B60-B4B0-711475C505DE.
Sep 17 23:05:19 Davids-iMac bootopsmobilev1[20349]: objc[20349]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x124c81910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x124aab210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 17 23:05:19 Davids-iMac bootopsmobilev1[20349]: assertion failed: 15G1004 14A345: libxpc.dylib + 62597 [37A9DF49-35C1-3D93-B854-B35CACF0100F]: 0x7d
Sep 17 23:05:19 Davids-iMac bootopsmobilev1[20349]: CONSOLE LOG file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:210:20: Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code snippets looks good except the part with the `HomeComponent` `template`, that Component declaration should look like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: "home",
    template: `<Label text="hello"></Label>`,
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router){
    }
}
```

The reason behind this is the fact that in NativeScript there is not webview it is all native components. So in order for your "hello" text to be rendered you need to use the NativeScript [Label](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/label). This is all true for NativeScript + Angular 2. Your code snippets work correctly on Angular 2 web because the web browser knows how to render that text, on the other hand NativeScripts Angular 2 renderer does not know how to render a text directly because on iOS and Android there is not such rendering and you need to tell it how via the `Label` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html, you have to put `<selector-for-the-page></selector-for-the-page>` You might have different selector.